# Use index values as category values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a following dataframe:

```
                  beat1   beat2   beat3   beat4   beat5   beat6   beat7  
filename                                                                  
M40_HC_503d.dat  0.7456  0.8574  0.7695  0.8698  0.8315  0.7908  0.8823   
M30_HC_461d.dat  0.7672  0.6682  0.7452  0.6853  0.7488  0.6782  0.6648   
M24_HC_459d.dat  0.6041  0.6439  0.5870  0.7452  0.6714  0.6684  0.6198   
M48_HC_543d.dat  0.8949  0.8570  0.9338  1.0545  1.0681  1.0775  0.8425   
M40_HC_506d.dat  0.7862  0.8917  0.9357  0.8250  0.8521  0.7146  0.7125
```

I want to make another dataframe in which the column names `beat1` to `beat7` would be indexes and it would have two columns. In the first column of this dataframe, the values would be all the values from `beat1` to `beat7` and the second column would be a `filename` from which the value comes. Something like this:

```
    values   filename
ind   
0   0.7456  M40_HC_503d.dat
1   0.8574  M40_HC_503d.dat
2   0.7695  M40_HC_503d.dat
3   0.8698  M40_HC_503d.dat
4   0.8315  M40_HC_503d.dat
5   0.7908  M40_HC_503d.dat
6   0.8823  M40_HC_503d.dat
7   0.7672  M30_HC_461d.dat
8   0.6682  M30_HC_461d.dat
9   0.7452  M30_HC_461d.dat
10  0.6853  M30_HC_461d.dat
11  0.7488  M30_HC_461d.dat
12  0.6782  M30_HC_461d.dat
13  0.6648  M30_HC_461d.dat
```

I tried many things including taking transpose and so on but nothing worked for me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
v = df.values
i = df.index.values

pd.DataFrame(
    np.hstack([v.reshape(-1, 1), i.repeat(v.shape[1])[:, None]]),
    columns=['values', 'filename']
)

   values         filename
0  0.7456  M40_HC_503d.dat
1  0.8574  M40_HC_503d.dat
2  0.7695  M40_HC_503d.dat
3  0.8698  M40_HC_503d.dat
4  0.8315  M40_HC_503d.dat
5  0.7908  M40_HC_503d.dat
6  0.8823  M40_HC_503d.dat
7  0.7672  M30_HC_461d.dat
8  0.6682  M30_HC_461d.dat
9  0.7452  M30_HC_461d.dat
...
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df = df.stack().reset_index(0, name='values')
print (df)
              filename  values
beat1  M40_HC_503d.dat  0.7456
beat2  M40_HC_503d.dat  0.8574
beat3  M40_HC_503d.dat  0.7695
beat4  M40_HC_503d.dat  0.8698
beat5  M40_HC_503d.dat  0.8315
beat6  M40_HC_503d.dat  0.7908
beat7  M40_HC_503d.dat  0.8823
beat1  M30_HC_461d.dat  0.7672
beat2  M30_HC_461d.dat  0.6682
beat3  M30_HC_461d.dat  0.7452
beat4  M30_HC_461d.dat  0.6853
beat5  M30_HC_461d.dat  0.7488
beat6  M30_HC_461d.dat  0.6782
...
```

Or maybe:

```
df = df.stack().reset_index(0, name='values').reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
           filename  values
0   M40_HC_503d.dat  0.7456
1   M40_HC_503d.dat  0.8574
2   M40_HC_503d.dat  0.7695
3   M40_HC_503d.dat  0.8698
4   M40_HC_503d.dat  0.8315
5   M40_HC_503d.dat  0.7908
6   M40_HC_503d.dat  0.8823
7   M30_HC_461d.dat  0.7672
8   M30_HC_461d.dat  0.6682
9   M30_HC_461d.dat  0.7452
10  M30_HC_461d.dat  0.6853
...
...
```

And if need change index:

```
df = df.stack().reset_index(0, name='values')
df.index = df.index.str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False)
print (df)
          filename  values
1  M40_HC_503d.dat  0.7456
2  M40_HC_503d.dat  0.8574
3  M40_HC_503d.dat  0.7695
4  M40_HC_503d.dat  0.8698
5  M40_HC_503d.dat  0.8315
6  M40_HC_503d.dat  0.7908
7  M40_HC_503d.dat  0.8823
1  M30_HC_461d.dat  0.7672
2  M30_HC_461d.dat  0.6682
...
...
```

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks